# Devise Password Reset Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have devise set up in my application and when i try to reset my password it generates these two URLs out of which only the first one works fine.

```
http://<domain>/password/edit?reset_password_token=SawsfhnpFRPHsxj_HjRhJ <--- works
http://<domain>/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=o1x1wFjQZxWnAug7K1zo
```

Any way to make sure it generates the right URL when a user wants to reset the password?

Routes

```
# Devise Authentication
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions" },
                                        :path => "",
                                        :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login',
                                                         :sign_out => 'logout',
                                                         :sign_up => 'signup',
                                                         :edit => 'profile/edit' }

  devise_scope :user do
    match '/update_password' => 'registrations#update_password', via: :post
  end
```

**app/views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb**

```
<p><%= link_to 'Click here', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %> to reset your password</p>
```

When i `rake routes` i am not finding the above routes.

Found these routes

```
user_password POST   /password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#create
                                   new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)                                         devise/passwords#new
                                  edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#edit
                                                     PATCH  /password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#update
                                                     PUT    /password(.:format)                                             devise/passwords#update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it inside the devise_for scope

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions" },
                                    :path => "",
                                    :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login',
                                                     :sign_out => 'logout',
                                                     :sign_up => 'signup',
                                                     :edit => 'profile/edit' } do
  match '/update_password' => 'users/registrations#update_password', via: :post
end
```